# newline in status_format in mutt

Tags: mutt

I wanted to play a bit with muttc configuration and in particular I tried to 
put a newline in my status_format (to have a two line status bar).

I tried to do it with `\n` and `\\n` but it only makes appear a `&` character...

Is there a way to do so?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works but It's not nice nor usable. Mutt apparently isn't ready to have multiline status line.

```
set status_format="-%r-Mutt: %f [Msgs:%?M?%M/?%m%?n? New:%n?%?o? Old:%o?%?d? Del:%d?%?F? Flag:%F?%?t? Tag:%t?%?p? Post:%p?%?b? Inc:%b?%?l? %l?]---(%s/%S)\n%>-(%P)---"
```

I tested it mutt 1.13.5, 1.5.24 and in neomutt 20200417. Both tested versions of mutt and even neomutt doesn't use the whole width of the last (second) line.

- It's possible to set more than 2 lines, but only first two are visible by default. When `status_on_top` is set, all lines are displayed but covers the index)
- Padding to the right works only on the last line.
- It intervenes in the *command prompt* or in the *index* when `status_on_top` is set (this makes it unusable)

  - You need to call *refresh* function (default `^Cl` binding) to redraw window after command prompt appears.

If you need to display more information in your status line and thus need more space:

- nobody cares about *Mutt* string or *sort/sort_aux* methods in the status line
- try to remove information you're not interested in at all
- hide what you're not interested under certain conditions

  - i.e.: `%?n?New: %n?` - to display count of new messages only if there are any.
  - see the notes about optional printing at the bottom of [3.363. status_format](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/#status-format)

[image: asciicast]